# Error en background Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

Por que al querer agregar un background a bootstrap 4 me lo coloca de la siguiente manera. Se supone que debería de correr bien a como lo tengo, estoy usando Angular para crear componentes pero al parecer es la principal razón por la que no esta visualizándose de la manera en que espero y no quiero ponerlo en los estilos globales que me da Angular ademas de que ni así me permite poner el background-color como quiero de todas formas.

Dejo en claro que quiero cubrir todo el espacio del navegador con dicho color.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo HTML**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center bg-warning">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Sing In</h3>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" alt="" />
      </figure>
      <form class="inp" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input id="_email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="login" />
        <br />
        <input
          id="_password"
          type="password"
          class="pass"
          placeholder="password"
        />
        <br />
        <button>Log in</button>
      </form>
      <div class="min-footer">
        <span>Forgot Password?</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 18px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  --mainGreen: #38d39f;
}

h3 {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--mainGreen);
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    outline-style: none;
}

button {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--mainGreen);
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline-style: none;
}

.email {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.min-footer {
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    color: var(--mainGreen);
}
```

Comment: para poder ayudarte debes poner tambien todo tu codigo css y poner para poder ejecutar el codigo y asi darnos mas informacion. Saludos

Comment: @Daniel no estoy usando realmente nada de codigo css para el background pero lo pondre como dices de todas formas.

Comment: Realmente si es necesario el css ya que sin estilos no estamos viendo nada , porque no utilizar `body` y agregas el color al fondo?

Comment: Porque en un componente de angular no existe el body, solo existe en el elemento global pero cambiaria el color de todos los nuevos componentes que quiera crear y es lo que no quiero realizar, ademas de que no es necesario el css porque bootstrap permite agregar un background-color con una clase de la propia libreria, por eso mencionaba que no era necesario :)

Comment: claro pero no hay ningun estilo de tus elementos xd, crear un div aparte con el tamaño y alto de la pagina y a ese div le agregas el color ??

Comment: @Daniel perfecto, funciono :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100065/discussion-between-asasced-and-daniel).